# TensorFlowJS Exception - Cannot start training because another fit() call is ongoing

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I used tf.expandDims() to add dimensions. Since I'm able to go into model.fit(), but got stuck due to this error **Cannot start training because another fit() call is ongoing.** and **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.** 
You can find my code here

```
// Train the model using the data. 
let tesnor_dim =[];
let tensr;for(var j=0; j<2; j++){ 
console.log('resize_image',resize_image);
tensr = tf.expandDims(ysarr[j], 0); 
tesnor_dim.push(tensr);
console.log('tesnor_dim',tesnor_dim);
    model.fit(resize_image[j], tesnor_dim[j], {epochs: 100}).then((loss) => {
         console.log('resize_image[j]',resize_image[j]);
         console.log('tesnor_dim[j]',tesnor_dim[j]);
         console.log('loss',loss);
         const t = model.predict(resize_image[j]);
         console.log('Prediction:::'+t);
         pred = t.argMax(1).dataSync(); // get the class of highest probability
                const labelsPred = Array.from(pred).map(e => setLabel[e])
                console.log('labelsPred:::'+labelsPred);
                //const saveResults = model.save('downloads://my-model-1');
                //console.log(saveResults);
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e.message);
            })
            }
```

Comment: It is a good practice to have a post for a single question. Can you move the question cannot read length of undefined in another post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiple `fit` are called on the same model, they have to be done sequentially. It means that the second call has to start only when the first one has completed. Using `async` and `await` will prevent your second call to happen unless the first has completed.

```
loss = await model.fit(resize_image[j], tesnor_dim[j], {epochs: 100})
// continue rest of processing
```

Answer (score -1):

you may use this code,

```
await model.fit(resize_image[j], tesnor_dim[j], {epochs: 100}).then((loss) => {
     console.log('resize_image[j]',resize_image[j]);
     console.log('tesnor_dim[j]',tesnor_dim[j]);
     console.log('loss',loss);
     const t = model.predict(resize_image[j]);
     console.log('Prediction:::'+t);
     pred = t.argMax(1).dataSync(); // get the class of highest probability
            const labelsPred = Array.from(pred).map(e => setLabel[e])
            console.log('labelsPred:::'+labelsPred);
            //const saveResults = model.save('downloads://my-model-1');
            //console.log(saveResults);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e.message);
        })
        }
```

Comment: using `await` and `then` in the same code is a bad practice since `await` is doing the same thing as  `then`