# Implement synchronous fit() or training function for tensorflow.js model

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have an agent for playing the game 'tic tac toe' using a tensorflow.js Neural Network in an attempt to mimic the behaviour of the Q function.

I am following this trip report but using TFJS and node: [Part 4 — Neural Network Q Learning](https://medium.com/@carsten.friedrich/part-4-neural-network-q-learning-a-tic-tac-toe-player-that-learns-kind-of-2090ca4798d)

The agent keeps track of the game states during a game and after the game is complete attempts to train the NN with updated Q values for those states depending on how the game ended.

My problem is: fit() is an async function and my script to play games runs a loop of games, the loop of games completes and then I get a bunch of UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning because of the calls to fit() from all the previous games are ongoing.

Is there a way to train my model synchronously at the end of every game. Perhaps using model.makeTrainFunction() or is there a way to use the optimizer? (optimizer.applyGradients() found in [cart-pole example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/cart-pole/index.js))

Link to my code [NNQPlayer.js](https://github.com/PaulBunker/Naughts-and-Crosses/blob/stack-overflow-fit-question/src/NNQPlayer.js)

Thanks for reading my question. I hope someone can give me a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: As a good rule of thumb try to always narrow down the problem by giving directly relevant code here instead of asking people to go and have a look at a bunch of code on github, though you can provide the link

Comment: Noted. I'll be more conciencus in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fit` is an async operation. If you are looking for a way to call `fit` multiple times, you simply needs to use `await` before calling `fit`. This will make sure that `fit` operation completes before another call to `fit`. you can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899687/tensorflowjs-exception-cannot-start-training-because-another-fit-call-is-ong)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had a few loops and it turns out I had to add await all the way up to the top to get it working.